# Protractor check if element is present on a LIST using element.all

Tags: angularjs, selenium, webdriver, protractor

I need to do an assertion to check if an element is present inside 'elements.all'.

My first idea is to run a for loop and put an expect inside. Not a great idea because it is checking every single items on list. So if I have 30 items, I might end up with 29 fails.

```js
element.all(by.css(element)).then(function(itemList) {
  console.log("Total values in dropdown are: " + itemList.length);
  for (i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
    itemList[i].getText().then(function(text) {
      console.log(text);
      expect(text).toEqual('whatever-i-need-to-assert');
    });
  };
});
```

In order to solve this problem, I nest an IF statement that will 'pre-check' for a string match. Another bad idea because if there is no match, my expect will never run, thus, giving me a false pass:

```js
element.all(by.css(".item a.gc-exercises-link")).then(function(itemList) {
  console.log("Total values in dropdown are: " + itemList.length);
  for (i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
    itemList[i].getText().then(function(text) {
      console.log(text);
      if (text == 'BOATLIFT-EXERCISE') {
        console.log('Match');
        expect(text).toEqual('BOATLIFT-EXERCISE');
      } else {
        console.log('No Match');
      };
    });
  };
});
```

Clearly, I am in the wrong path here. Can someone give me an idea how to properly expect for a 'Text' when using element.all. I just need to prove that a text is present on the said list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example to check that there is a link with the text "Terms" in a page :

```
browser.get('https://www.google.co.uk/');
expect(element.all(by.css('a')).getText()).toContain('Terms');
```

Note that for each element, protractor needs to interogate the browser, which could be slow especially if there is a lot of elements.

A quicker solution would be to check that at least one element is present with a XPath including the expected text:

```
browser.get('https://www.google.co.uk/');
expect(element.all(by.xpath("//a[text()='Terms']")).count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```

Comment: Thank you! This one worked. I am finding an item in the list that is almost 30-100 indexes long. and upon testing it, I just added roughly 2 seconds to my test. Something that is acceptable at this stage for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check it's present (and other list item's won't interfere), you could call `.getText()` on the array after element.all, before `.then` and use `toContain()`

```
element.all(by.css(".item a.gc-exercises-link")).getText().then(function(itemList) {
    expect(itemList).toContain('some text');
};
```

Or if you know the index:

```
element.all(by.css(".item a.gc-exercises-link")).getText().then(function(itemList) {
    expect(itemList[3]).toEqual('some text');
}
```

As a side note: you can use `.each()` instead of creating a for loop https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function.

```
$$("span").filter(function(elem,index){
    return elem.getText().then(function(txt){
        return txt === 'text to compare';
    });
}).then(function(eleList){   // you get the list of elements containing the text here
    console.log(eleList.length);
});
```